# Failed tests with assertion error displayed as broken in allure

Tags: junit5, allure

In test result:

> junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: expected:<1> but was:<2>

In Allure:

test broken

I need to make it failed in Allure.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this plugin in your pom.xml ?
If no, try to add

```
<plugin>
<groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
<artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
<version>2.9</version>
<configuration>
<reportVersion>2.6.0</reportVersion>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```